# What's XmlNodeType.Document ? Difference between XmlNodeType.Element and XmlNodeType.Document

Tags: c#, xml, xmlreader

I am using XmlReader to read an XML File and I want to count XML Element right under of Document Element that as I know it should be the root element.

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewsLetters>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
</NewsLetters>
```

C# Code :

```
public static string TotalMemberCount()
{
    XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Newsletter/NewsLetter.xml"));

    int totalCount = 0;
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.Document)
            totalCount++;
    }

    return totalCount.ToString();
}
```

**Normally I was expecting 4 records but it returns 5 because it also counts the root element.** What should I do ? Actually I know how to solve with using XDocument,XElement and LINQ but I want to solve in this way, don't ask me why because I want to learn every way in which I can solve such problems.

Thanks in advance.

Sincerely....

Comment: No answer ? Saddening...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you've come up with is flawed in at least five different ways.

1. It's certainly not a "generic solution", since your code is now completely dependent on information in the XML - your method can only count elements properly if the XML document it's processing contains the flag attribute that you've added.
2. The flag attribute's unnecessary.  Any time an `XmlReader` starts at the beginning of the stream it's reading, the first element it reads is *always* going to be the top-level element.  It can't possibly be anything else.  Instead of adding an attribute to your document to identify the top-level element, you can just use a flag to track whether or not you've read the top-level element yet.  Or heck, you can just subtract 1 from the total.
3. And even if you *did* need the flag attribute, you're doing it wrong.  You're using `MoveToFirstAttribute` to find it.  What if there's more than one atttribute on the element?  What if the first attribute your code finds whose value is `True` isn't `Root`?  And what if one of the child elements has an attribute on it with that value?  If you're going to use an attribute for this purpose, you should, at the *very* least, search for it by name.
4. This code won't count all *child* elements of the top-level element, it will count all *descendant* elements.  The reader moves from node to node in document order.  If an element node has a child node, that child node is the next node that gets read by `Read()`.  There are methods of the `XmlReader` that you can use to read an entire element and all of its content in one single gulp, but you're not using them.
5. The condition `reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element` is redundant:  there's no way that a node can be an XML declaration if it's an element.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways, I found my own solution, what I was trying to achieve is to find a generic solution so I came up with such a solution :

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<NewsLetters Root="True">
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
  <EMail Date="10/10/2009">hello@hello.com</EMail>
</NewsLetters>
```

**C#**

```
   public static string TotalMemberCount()
    {
        int totalCount = 0;
        using (XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Newsletter/NewsLetter.xml")))
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader.NodeType != XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration && reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                {
                    if (reader.MoveToFirstAttribute())
                    {
                        if (reader.Value == "True")
                            //gotcha, I don't want this,this is root element
                            continue;
                    }
                    totalCount++;
                }
            }
            return totalCount.ToString();
        }

    }
```